# How can I make a SVG group follow a gradient in a circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to animate a circle being drained, with is working well. However I want a "marker" to follow the drain level, and I'm having difficulties understanding how to do this.

I already made a example embedded in this post, where the circle fill animates, and the number animates.

The final state can be seen here:

[image: Final state of the animation]

The issue is; that I want to place the "XXX used" marker based on the drain percentage. But I have had little luck figuring out how to achieve this.

So it has to move up and down, but also left and right depending on the percentage.

My code is as follows:

```js
const usedAmount = 200;
const totalAmount = 400;

const radius = 120;

const valuePercent = (usedAmount / totalAmount) * 100;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

 let grad = svg
   .append("defs")
     .append("linearGradient")
       .attr("id", "grad")
       .attr("x1", "0%")
       .attr("x2", "0%")
       .attr("y1", "0%")
       .attr("y2", "0%");

grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "1%").style("stop-color", '#000');
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "1%").style("stop-color", '#ccc');

let arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius( radius - 40 )
  .outerRadius( radius )
  .endAngle(2 * Math.PI)
  .startAngle(0 * Math.PI);

let cutout = svg.select('defs')
  .append('clipPath')
  .attr('clip-rule', 'evenodd')
  .attr('id', 'cutout')
  .append("path")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('clip-rule', 'evenodd')
  .attr('fill', '#ccc');

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", radius)
  .attr("cy", radius)
  .attr("r", radius)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#cutout)") // Apply the mask
  .attr("fill", "url(#grad)");

grad
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .ease(d3.easeQuad)
  .delay(300)
  .attr("y1", valuePercent + 1 + '%');

var marker = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'gauge__fillup__follow')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 + "," + 50 + ")");

marker.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("width", 35)
  .attr("height", 3);

marker.append('svg:text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('z-index', '4')
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('dy', 12)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
  .datum({textContent: ''})
  .text(200)
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .delay(300)
  .ease(d3.easeQuad)
  .tween("text", function(d) {
  const i = d3.interpolate(0, this.textContent, d);
  return (t) => {
    d3.select(this).text(Math.round(i(t)));
  };
});

marker.append('svg:text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('color', 'white')
  .attr('z-index', '4')
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 16)
  .attr('dy', 12)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
  .text('used');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="500" width="500"></svg>
```

Ended up with this result: https://codepen.io/Saturate/pen/BROzBe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to translate the group down by the same amount:

```
marker.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .ease(d3.easeQuad)
    .delay(300)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 220 + "," 
        + ((usedAmount / totalAmount) * (radius * 2)) + ")");
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const usedAmount = 200;
const totalAmount = 400;

const radius = 120;

const valuePercent = (usedAmount / totalAmount) * 100;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

let grad = svg
    .append("defs")
    .append("linearGradient")
    .attr("id", "grad")
    .attr("x1", "0%")
    .attr("x2", "0%")
    .attr("y1", "0%")
    .attr("y2", "0%");

grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "1%").style("stop-color", '#000');
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "1%").style("stop-color", '#ccc');

let arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - 40)
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .endAngle(2 * Math.PI)
    .startAngle(0 * Math.PI);

let cutout = svg.select('defs')
    .append('clipPath')
    .attr('clip-rule', 'evenodd')
    .attr('id', 'cutout')
    .append("path")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')')
    .attr('d', arc)
    .attr('clip-rule', 'evenodd')
    .attr('fill', '#ccc');

svg.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", radius)
    .attr("cy", radius)
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#cutout)") // Apply the mask
    .attr("fill", "url(#grad)");

grad
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .ease(d3.easeQuad)
    .delay(300)
    .attr("y1", valuePercent + 1 + '%');

var marker = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'gauge__fillup__follow')
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 220 + "," + 0 + ")");

marker.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 1)
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("width", 35)
    .attr("height", 3);

marker.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('z-index', '4')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', -6)
    .attr('dy', 12)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
    .datum({
        textContent: ''
    })
    .text(200)
    .transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .delay(300)
    .ease(d3.easeQuad)
    .tween("text", function(d) {
        const i = d3.interpolate(0, this.textContent, d);
        return (t) => {
            d3.select(this).text(Math.round(i(t)));
        };
    });

marker.append('svg:text')
    .attr('class', 'label')
    .attr('color', 'white')
    .attr('z-index', '4')
    .attr('x', 50)
    .attr('y', 10)
    .attr('dy', 12)
    .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
    .text('used');

marker.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .ease(d3.easeQuad)
    .delay(300)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 220 + "," + ((usedAmount / totalAmount )*(radius*2)) + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="500" width="500"></svg>
```

EDIT: Here is the translation with `attrTween`, going from up to down and left to right:

```
marker.transition()
    .duration(3000)
    .ease(d3.easeQuad)
    .delay(300)
    .attrTween("transform", function() {
        return function(t) {
            return "translate(" + (radius * (1 + (Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 * t)))) + "," 
            + (((usedAmount / totalAmount) * (radius * 2)) * (1 - (Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 * t)))) + ")"
        }
    });
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const usedAmount = 200;
const totalAmount = 400;

const radius = 120;

const valuePercent = (usedAmount / totalAmount) * 100;

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

let grad = svg
  .append("defs")
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", "grad")
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "0%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "1%").style("stop-color", '#000');
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "1%").style("stop-color", '#ccc');

let arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 40)
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .endAngle(2 * Math.PI)
  .startAngle(0 * Math.PI);

let cutout = svg.select('defs')
  .append('clipPath')
  .attr('clip-rule', 'evenodd')
  .attr('id', 'cutout')
  .append("path")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + radius + ',' + radius + ')')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('clip-rule', 'evenodd')
  .attr('fill', '#ccc');

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", radius)
  .attr("cy", radius)
  .attr("r", radius)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#cutout)") // Apply the mask
  .attr("fill", "url(#grad)");

grad
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .ease(d3.easeQuad)
  .delay(300)
  .attr("y1", valuePercent + 1 + '%');

var marker = svg.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'gauge__fillup__follow')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (radius) + "," + 0 + ")");

marker.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 1)
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("width", 35)
  .attr("height", 3);

marker.append('svg:text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('z-index', '4')
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', -6)
  .attr('dy', 12)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
  .datum({
    textContent: ''
  })
  .text(200)
  .transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .delay(300)
  .ease(d3.easeQuad)
  .tween("text", function(d) {
    const i = d3.interpolate(0, this.textContent, d);
    return (t) => {
      d3.select(this).text(Math.round(i(t)));
    };
  });

marker.append('svg:text')
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('color', 'white')
  .attr('z-index', '4')
  .attr('x', 50)
  .attr('y', 10)
  .attr('dy', 12)
  .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
  .text('used');

marker.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .ease(d3.easeQuad)
  .delay(300)
  .attrTween("transform", function() {
    return function(t) {
      return "translate(" + (radius * (1 + (Math.sin(Math.PI / 2 * t)))) + "," + (((usedAmount / totalAmount) * (radius * 2)) * (1 - (Math.cos(Math.PI / 2 * t)))) + ")"
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg height="500" width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: This solved the top to bottom approach, but how about moving it left and right, so it fits with the circle?

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed the "left and right" part. I made another function in the edit... the math is far from perfect (I'm sleeping here), but you can improve it.

Comment: Thanks! This will make me able to do the math, and fix it up :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your question made me realize that i didn't understand trigonometry as well as i would like, so i took a stab at it. Once i learned the fundamentals of pi and sine, the answer became quite clear.

Great article i read that led me to my answer: https://betterexplained.com/articles/intuitive-understanding-of-sine-waves/

https://jsfiddle.net/zk0wsq5a/2/

```
marker.transition()
  .duration(3000)
  .ease(d3.easeQuad)
  .delay(300)
  .attrTween("transform", function() {
    return function(t) {
        let distance = Math.PI * t * (usedAmount / totalAmount)
        let x = radius + (radius * Math.sin(distance))
        let y = radius * (1-Math.cos(distance))
      return `translate(${x} ,${y})`
    }
  });
```